# How do I make a text field like a "To:" field on facebook's "New Message" window?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, forms

I want to know how to make text field like below by using JavaScript and HTML.

[image: Screenshot of Facebook's "New Message" prompt]

This text field highlights username with blue box.

Do you know any good tutorials?

Comment: screenshot + an explanation of which functionality you actually *want* to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If jQuery is alright with you, then number of plugins with tutorials could be found. For examples,

- [jQuery TextExt Plugin](http://textextjs.com/)
- [jQuery Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)